# Gatsby Declarative Routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Hellou. Currently I am trying to move create react app to Gatsby. In CRA I have declared my routes in this way.

> routes.js

```
    /* eslint-disable react/no-multi-comp */
/* eslint-disable react/display-name */
import React, { lazy } from 'react'
import { Redirect } from '@reach/router'

import MainLayout from './layouts/MainLayout'
import LandingPage from './containers/LandingPage'

const routes = [
  {
    route: '*',
    component: MainLayout,
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/',
        exact: true,
        component: LandingPage,
      },
      {
        path: '/login',
        exact: true,
        component: lazy(() => import('./containers/Login')),
      },
      {
        path: '/register',
        exact: true,
        component: lazy(() => import('./containers/Register')),
      },
      {
        path: '/password/reset',
        exact: true,
        component: lazy(() => import('./containers/PasswordReset')),
      },
      {
        path: '/password/token/:token',
        exact: true,
        component: lazy(() => import('./containers/PasswordReset')),
      },
      {
        path: '/password/request/:status',
        exact: true,
        component: lazy(() => import('./containers/Confirmation')),
      },
      {
        path: 'email/confirmation',
        exact: true,
        component: lazy(() => import('./containers/Confirmation')),
      },
      {
        path: '/blog',
        exact: true,
        component: lazy(() => import('./containers/Blog/Home')),
      },
      {
        component: () => <Redirect to="/errors/error-404" />,
      },
    ],
  },
]

export default routes
```

This is my app.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router } from '@reach/router'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import CookiesProvider from 'react-cookie/cjs/CookiesProvider'
import { Cookies } from 'react-cookie'
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import { setAuthToken } from '../services';
import { setCurrentUser, logoutUser } from '../store/actions/authActions';
import store from '../store/store'
import Alert from '../components/Alert'
import { H_JWT_COOKIE } from '../constants/constants';

import { renderRoutes } from 'react-router-config';

import routes from '../routes'

// Check for token
const cookie = new Cookies()
if(cookie.get(H_JWT_COOKIE)) {
  // Set AuthToken
  setAuthToken(cookie.get(H_JWT_COOKIE));
  // Decode token and get user info and expiration
  const decoded = jwt_decode(cookie.get(H_JWT_COOKIE));
  // Set user and isAuthenticated
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));

  // Chek for expired token
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000
  if(decoded.exo < currentTime) {
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());
    window.location.href = '/login';
  }
}


const App = () => {
  return (
    <CookiesProvider>
        <Provider store ={store}>
          <Router  >
          <Alert />
            {renderRoutes(routes)}

          </Router>

        </Provider>
    </CookiesProvider>



  );
};

export default App
```

Is there any tutorials how to handle routing in Gatby in similar way?
I want to be able to create the dynamic urls. Could I use this react-router-config in Gatsby. 
I am trying to use renderRoutes in gatsby-node.js but it is unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to get much benefit from Gatsby if you're using a client-side rendered approach like this. Consider rendering pages with skeletons and updating props when authentication is resolved. At least this way public content and your base HTML document can be statically rendered in advance. You'd also want to switch to using webpack to handle imports (no dynamic importing) on a per-page basis, letting Gatsby orchestrate the default Reach Router settings.